# 950M faster than a 970M?

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, nvidia

I'm currently testing some code for a friend of mine as I have access to a bunch of different MXM modules and I got some odd results benchmarking some code between a 950M and a 970M.

```
int main(void)
{
    static const int WORK_SIZE = 65530;
    float *data = new float[WORK_SIZE];

    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

        initialize (data, WORK_SIZE);

        float *recCpu = cpuReciprocal(data, WORK_SIZE);
        float *recGpu = gpuReciprocal(data, WORK_SIZE);
        float cpuSum = std::accumulate (recCpu, recCpu+WORK_SIZE, 0.0);
        float gpuSum = std::accumulate (recGpu, recGpu+WORK_SIZE, 0.0);

        cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);

        /* Verify the results */
        std::cout << i << ") gpuSum = "<<gpuSum<< " cpuSum = " <<cpuSum<< " time = " <<time<< std::endl;

        delete[] recCpu;
        delete[] recGpu;
    }

    /* Free memory */
    delete[] data;

    return 0;
}
```

I ran the test 3 times on both cards and the 950M averaged around 7 seconds while the 970M averaged around 9 seconds. In addition, I ran the benchmark program that is included in the CUDA toolkit and only got 3GB/s H-D speeds on the 970 vs 10GB/s on the 950. This was done on a Skylake Xeon running Ubuntu 14.04 and CUDA 7.5. Can anyone shed some light on this discrepancy? The code for cpuReciprocal and gpuReciprocal is below.

```
/**
 * CUDA kernel that computes reciprocal values for a given vector
 */
__global__ void reciprocalKernel(float *data, unsigned vectorSize) {
    unsigned idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    if (idx < vectorSize)
        data[idx] = 1.0/data[idx];
}

/**
 * Host function that copies the data and launches the work on GPU
 */
float *gpuReciprocal(float *data, unsigned size)
{
    float *rc = new float[size];
    float *gpuData;

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMalloc((void **)&gpuData, sizeof(float)*size));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMemcpy(gpuData, data, sizeof(float)*size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    static const int BLOCK_SIZE = 256;
    const int blockCount = (size+BLOCK_SIZE-1)/BLOCK_SIZE;
    reciprocalKernel<<<blockCount, BLOCK_SIZE>>> (gpuData, size);

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMemcpy(rc, gpuData, sizeof(float)*size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaFree(gpuData));
    return rc;
}

float *cpuReciprocal(float *data, unsigned size)
{
    float *rc = new float[size];
    for (unsigned cnt = 0; cnt < size; ++cnt) rc[cnt] = 1.0/data[cnt];
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: The 970 had the wrong BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bandwidth of host to device is given by PCI express performance. It seems that the 950 is connected with PCI Express Gen 3 16x, where the 970 seems to be at 4x. The hardware setup being not detailed It is the most likely explanation.
NVIDIA tools such as nvidia-smi will provide you with this information.
As for your algorithm, the slowest part is communication with host, next in line is device memory bandwidth about 10 times faster, and finally the divide.

Comment: Thank you! According to SMI, my 970 is running in gen 1. However, I know that my board supports gen 3 and I know my 950 was in gen 3. Is this a known issue with the 970?

Comment: @apizzi, it is a matter of BIOS configuration, motherboard and CPU capability. You want to check all these to ensure the link is Gen 3. Are these MXM modules of full PCIe cards on a desktop ?